# Nullability and generics in .NET 6

Tags: c#, .net, generics, .net-6.0, nullable-reference-types

Let's say we have some generic method with 2 parameters:

```
private void TestConstraints<TKey>(TKey key, TKey? nullableKey)
    where TKey : notnull { }
```

That's perfectly fine from .NET6 perspective, where not nullable reference types were added. But using attempt is failing with reason CS8714 type can't be used as parameter:

```
private void TestMethod()
{
    var id = 5;
    int? nullableId = null;
    TestConstraints(id, nullableId);
}
```

> Warning   CS8714  The type 'int?' cannot be used as type parameter 'TKey' in the generic type or method 'TestClass.TestConstraints(TKey, TKey?)'. Nullability of type argument 'int?' doesn't match 'notnull' constraint.

Specifying type explicitly as `int` does not help.

Could someone clarify if I could operate this way (defining input parameters as `TKey?`) or not, and where in documentation it is stated?

Compiler version:

> Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 17.2.0+41abc5629

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For unconstrained (neither to `struct` nor to `class`) generic type parameter `T` - `T?` is handled differently for value types and reference types. From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics):

> - If the type argument for `T` is a reference type, `T?` references the corresponding nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string`, then `T?` is a `string?`.
> - **If the type argument for `T` is a value type, `T?` references the same value type, `T`. For example, if `T` is an `int`, the `T?` is also an `int`.**
> - If the type argument for `T` is a nullable reference type, `T?` references that same nullable reference type. For example, if `T` is a `string?`, then `T?` is also a `string?`.
> - **If the type argument for `T` is a nullable value type, `T?` references that same nullable value type. For example, if `T` is a `int?`, then `T?` is also a `int?`.**

This happens partially due to the differences in how nullable reference and nullable value types are handled, because nullable value types are actually separate types - [`Nullable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.nullable-1?view=net-6.0).

For `TestConstraints` let's imagine that `T` is `int` then according to the rules the signature becomes `TestConstraints<int>(int key, int nullableKey)` which obviously will not compile for the `TestConstraints<int>(id, nullableId)` call due to the type mismatch (`TestConstraints<int>(id, nullableId.Value)` will compile but throw at the runtime).

For `int?` (`Nullable<int>`) the signature becomes `TestConstraints<int?>(int? key, int? nullableKey)` which will compile (due to the implicit conversion `T` -> `Nullable<T>`) but obviously will fail the generic constraint with the warning.

The workaround can be to introduce two overloads, one for `struct`, one for `class` and let the compiler [figure it out](https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTADAWAFCwIzIMQDsCuAbPAQwCM8BTAAjKxPOWVgoFkBPAYz2QG9kK+KADgCcAlgDdCAF0pQALBQAqZAM6SAwgHssqoYRFZJygDwKA0mRYA+ABRmLFANYWANIvMsA/BVwFaZdwCUvPwhAO4AFmRClHYsFCAUOjhsksF8XBQAvmkUOcLiUjLySqqa2pK6+oYm7jaxji5uFl4+RKT+FkFIIWGR0U1xCbA5Gdnd/HmiEtIUcooqkkxkkuEawNZdITzjPRQSQhQiwBQAvBQArADcOSFVLfht5ACSx2et1zs9JepaOnoGymsR1crT8LwCH12fG+ZT+VWMUFQcBsACIUSCHhCcmNMkA==):

```cs
private void TestConstraints<TKey>(TKey key, TKey? nullableKey)
        where TKey : struct
    { }
    
private void TestConstraints<TKey>(TKey key, TKey? nullableKey)
        where TKey : class
    { }
```

Comment: That’s exactly what I expected, but got CS8714 for first argument

Comment: @Norritt I don't understand what you have expected, cause this rules I would say explain the CS8714.

Comment: My `TestConstraints` method has parameters `TKey, TKey?`, not two `TKey`s. Obviously I can’t expect `int?` would be accepted as `TKey`, but it should be accepted as `TKey?`

Comment: @Norritt I know. As quoted from the docs - since `TKey` is not constrained to `class` or `struct` for value types `TKey` and `TKey?` will be treated as the same type.