# Casting object? to a generic type that may or may not be nullable

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-6.0, c#-10.0

I'm trying to convert a project to use nullable reference types, but I'm running into an issue. In my project, I have a place where I get an `object?` that needs to be cast to a generic type `T` before adding it to a collection. The type `T` could be anything; a nullable reference type, a non-nullable reference type, or a value type. This isn't known at compile time.

So, let's say I have the following code (toy example):

```cs
static T Convert<T>(object? value)
{
    return (T)value;
}
```

This causes the compiler to complain that value may be null, and that the return of the function may be null. That's fair enough, since if `T` is non-nullable and value is `null`, this wouldn't be allowed. I thought maybe this would work:

```cs
static T Convert<T>(object? value)
{
    if (value == null)
        return default;
    else
        return (T)value;
}
```

But this has the same problem: if `T` is a non-nullable reference type, `default` is still `null`, which still violates the constraint.

Making the function return `T?` is not a solution, because in the case of value types, I don't want to use `Nullable<T>`.

I thought about throwing an exception if `value` is `null`, but I want to allow null if `T` is nullable. So I'd only want to throw that if `T` is non-nullable, and that kind of generic specialization doesn't seem possible in C#.

The context here is that I'm using a `TypeConverter`, and unfortunately the result of conversion is allowed to return `null`.

Is there a good way to handle this situation?

Comment: I think that using constraints might help (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) but I'm not sure if the type system is strong enough to help in this case.

Comment: Constraints aren't the answer unfortunately because I want to allow all cases. This code has to work for nullable reference types, non-nullable reference types, and structs. It's also not possible to specialize to handle them separately.

Comment: _"Making the function return T? is not a solution, because in the case of value types, I don't want to use Nullable<T>."_ -  it would not be ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72911969/2501279)) - for unconstrained `T` `T?` for value types  will be treated as `T`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use C# 9.0 or higher, you can use return type of `T?` without need to resort to `Nullable<T>`. For generics in non-nullable context there is special set of rules, detailed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/nullable-references#generics).

> If the type argument for T is a value type, T? references the same value type, T. For example, if T is an int, the T? is also an int.

You can check `GetType()` of `T` with simple console application. If `T` is `int`, return type will be `System.Int32`, not `Nullable<System.Int32>`.

```cs
#nullable enable
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var result = Convert<int>(null);
        Console.WriteLine(result); // Prints: 0
        Console.WriteLine(result.GetType().FullName); // Prints: System.Int32
    }

    static T? Convert<T>(object? value)
    {
        if (value is null)
            return default(T);
        return (T)value;
    }
}
```

C# Playground example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZJQt2E).