# Cast Expression<Func<T>> to specific type

Tags: c#, annotations, blazor, func, mudblazor

In a Blazor component, I have the following parameter. `For` is used to get some custom data annotations via reflection, e.g. to display an Asterisk * if a property is required and extract the label names based on data annotations

```cs
[Parameter]
public Expression<Func<T?>>? For { get; set; }

public Expression<Func<DateTime?>>? ForDateTime
{
    get
    {
        if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
        {
            //return <Func<DateTime?>>? here
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTimeOffset))
        {
            //return <Func<DateTime?>>? here
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    set
    {
        //For = set value of Expression<Func<T?>>? here
    }
}
```

How can I cast this to `Expression<Func<DateTime?>>? ForDateTime { get; set; }` and back if `T` is of Type `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset`.

The reason for that is I am using [MudBlazor](https://mudblazor.com/) and want to call

```
<MudDatePicker For="@(ForDateTime)" Variant="Variant.Outlined"/>
```

But there an `Expression<Func<DateTime?>>?` is needed.

For now I created a `ExpressionVisitor` like that:

```cs
public class TypeConverterVisitor<T, TU> : ExpressionVisitor
{
    protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
    {
        if (node.Type == typeof(T?) || node.Type == typeof(T))
        {
            return Expression.Parameter(typeof(TU?));
        }

        return base.VisitParameter(node);
    }
}
```

which I use like that:

```cs
var visitor = new TypeConverterVisitor<T, DateTime?>();
var expression = (Expression<Func<DateTime?>>)visitor.Visit(For);
return expression;
```

But this only works if my `For` is actually a (nullable) `DateTime?` already. I want it to be able to cast (non nullable) `DateTime` and `DateTimeOffset` as well. But I am not sure where I can handle this conversion. Especially as a breakpoint in the `VisitParameter` method is never hit.

Comment: The answer by @Guru below gives you a way to do this, but I wonder if you could remove the `ForDateTime` property altogether and just use a generic version. For example:  `public Expression<Func<U>>? ForType<U>() => (Expression<Func<U>>)(object)For;` and then use it like this: `<MudDatePicker For="@(ForType<DateTime?>())" ...`

Comment: What the question asks is how Blazor data-binding already works. You don't need `For` to bind a component property to a value, or cascade a parameter to a nested component. One option is to have the nested component bind to a component property that's bound in the page's model. The other is to use cascading parameters so you don't have to specify any intermediate properties

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I use `For` to get some custom data annotations via reflection, e.g. to display an Asterisk `*` if a property is required and extract the label names based on data annotations.

Comment: `() => (DateTime?)value`?

Comment: @Pieterjan This does not help as I need to use the expression directly. When using a parameter in between reflection gives me the value of that parameter but nor from the original property.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need the `else`. Just `return null`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using object indirection, but only if the `T` is constrained to `struct` (due to specifics of how `T?` is handled with introduction of nullable reference types - for example see [Nullability and generics in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72911604/2501279)):

```
class Test<T> where T : struct
{
    public Expression<Func<T?>>? For { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<DateTime?>>? ForDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                return (Expression<Func<DateTime?>>)(object)For;
            }
            // ...
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            //For = set value of Expression<Func<T?>>? here
        }
    }
}
```

**UPD**:

If you can't constraint the class then you can rebuild expression tree. Something to get you started:

```
class Test<T>
{
    public Expression<Func<T?>>? For { get; set; }

    public Expression<Func<DateTime?>>? ForDateTime
    {
        get
        {
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime))
            {
                if (For is not null)
                {
                    var newBody = Expression.Convert(For.Body, typeof(DateTime?));
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<DateTime?>>(newBody);
                }
                return null;
            }
            if (typeof(T) == typeof(DateTime?))
            {
                
                return  (Expression<Func<DateTime?>>)(object)For;
            }
            // ...
            else
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            //For = set value of Expression<Func<T?>>? here
        }
    }
}
```

```
var forDateTime = new Test<DateTime>
    {
        For = () => DateTime.Now
    }
    .ForDateTime
    .Compile()();

var forDateTimeNull = new Test<DateTime?>
    {
        For = () => null
    }
    .ForDateTime
    .Compile()();
```

Comment: While this will work, there's no reason for such code in the first place. Blazor data binding works without requiring `Expression` properties. I suspect the OP is trying to rebuild data binding

Comment: Unfortunately I can not constrain it so struct

Comment: @Patrick then you will need to reassemble the expression tree and use some conversions during the process, because  without constraint for  `Test<DateTime>`  `T?` will also be `DateTime`., i.e. stored `For`  would actually be `Expression<Func<DateTime>>`  and not `Expression<Func<DateTime?>>`

Comment: @GuruStron I just tried that using a custom `TypeConverterVisitor` class (added to my question). But as I am pretty new to Expressions etc. I am stuck now.

Comment: @Patrick `Func<DateTime?>` does not have parameters =))

Comment: As `Expression.Convert` returns a `UnaryExpression` which `MudBlazor` cannot handle, I tried to convert it to a `MemberExpression` using `if (unaryExpression.Operand is MemberExpression newBody) return Expression.Lambda<Func<DateTime?>>(newBody);` But then I get the same issue again: `Expression of type 'System.DateTime' cannot be used for return type 'System.Nullable\`1[System.DateTime]'`