# Implementing Interface with Generic Nullable Class

Tags: c#, .net

I'm using .NET 8 and I have this interface:

```cs
public interface ISortableParams<T>
{
    public bool? Descending { get; set; }
    public T? OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to implement it like this:

```cs
public enum OrderBy
{
    None = 0,
    Name = 1,
    Email = 2,
}
public class Request : ISortableParams<OrderBy>
{
    public bool? Descending { get; set; }

    // This property (OrderBy) is not recognized as implementation
    // Because it has nullable '?'. If I remove it, it works.
    // But the enum might be null.
    // This happen because Enum is a class type.
    // Are nullable classes not recognized as implicit implementation?
    public OrderBy? OrderBy { get; set; } 
}
```

- I don't want to implement the interface Explicitly.
- Adding `where T : struct` solves the problem, but I want to keep it completely generic with no restriction:

```cs
public interface ISortableParams<T> 
 where T : struct // this makes it work, but I might use a class sometime.
{
    public bool? Descending { get; set; }
    public T? OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

- How to solve it?

Comment: Why do you have this `interface ISortableParams<T>` in the first place? What problem are you trying to solve? (How is `T? OrderBy` supposed to represent an ordering rule or sorting-key-selector? I also note that you can't express _multiple_ ordering criteria using this approach).

Comment: @Dai It's more about unifying code style. It will be used mainly for ordering by one key, but can be used as multiple ordering if used as list param: `List<ISortableParams<string>>`.

Comment: How about `: ISortableParams<OrderBy?>`?

Comment: maybe you need to: 1: add `where T : notnull` constraint, 2: change type of `OrderBy` to `T` instead of `T?`. Your `OrderBy` enum type has a `None` value, after all, so there is no need to declare also nullability on the property, unless you intend to allow `T` to be any **class** or **interface** type, whose default/fallback would be `null`.

Comment: @Adnan It pains me to see you making the same mistakes I did, years ago, when I was learning about higher-order language-features (like generics) for the first time and seeing what kinds of clever tricks and neat things you can build with it - but I'll tell you right now that your approach really won't work (or rather: it won't scale to the kinds of complexities and edge-cases in the business-rules that inhabit practically every domain-model in software) - but don't let me stop you doing what you're doing - I'll wait for the tedium to sink-in at your end to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To tackle your issues at least partially:

> This property (OrderBy) is not recognized as implementation

Change generic parameter to be a nullable enum (`OrderBy?`):

```
public class Request : ISortableParams<OrderBy?>
{
    public bool? Descending { get; set; }

    public OrderBy? OrderBy { get; set; } 
}
```

And no constraint will be needed.

The issue here is that nullable reference and nullable value types are treated differently by C# compiler (for reference types nullability is basically a metadata while for value types it is represented in type system with `Nullable<T>` struct).

A bit more details:

- [Nullability and generics in .NET 6](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72911604/2501279)

Comment: Thanks, this solved the issue. I completely forgot about using it there.

Comment: ...how is the `ISortableParams<T>` interface meant to be consumed though?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement `ISortableParams<OrderBy?>` instead.

```cs
public class SortableParams : ISortableParams<OrderBy?>
{
    public bool? Descending { get; set; }
    public OrderBy? OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are missing is stating that OrderBy is nullable type in implemented class:

```
public class Request : ISortableParams<OrderBy?>
{
    public bool? Descending { get; set; }

    public OrderBy? OrderBy { get; set; }
}
```