Why C# null-state analysis fails for member access?
In the below code, why does the compiler null-state analysis fails to deduce that Age is not null and warning is produced? Even though the "if" explicitly verifies that. What would be the recommended way to resolve this warning here?
public class Person
{
    public double? Age { get; set; }
}

public class Dog
{
    public Person? Owner { get; set; }
}

public string GetOwnerAgeAsString(Dog dog)
{
    if ((dog.Owner != null) && (dog.Owner.Age != null))
        return dog.Owner.Age.ToString();  // <-- CS8603: Possible null reference return

    return "Unknown";
}

Surprisingly, adding the null-forgiving operator return dog.Owner.Age!.ToString(); doesn't solve the warning either.
Do I miss something basic here or is it a compiler bug?
(Using VS 17.10.1)

My guess is that properties could return different (possibly null) things every time you access them. (even though the compiler should know that these are auto properties...) Does the warning go away if you assign dog.Owner & dog.Owner.Age to intermediate local variables and check those instead?

Nullable<double>.ToString can return null. Use dog.Owner.Age.GetValueOrDefault().ToString() instead

@ipodtouch0218 What you say is very logical, but no. Assigning to a temporary variable doesn't resolve it. Moreover, the same logic of accessing twice would justify warning on Owner access, but for that compiler does deduce non-null state.

object.ToString() returns nullable string:
public virtual string? ToString ();

Which can be changed by the overridden implementation (like for example double does), but Nullable<T> does not change the nullability of the returned string:
public override string? ToString() => hasValue ? value.ToString() : "";

Hence the warning you see.
One of the fixes is to use the ! operator at the end of the expression:
return dog.Owner.Age.ToString()!;

or use Value:
return dog.Owner.Age.Value.ToString();


Thank you! I think that the most basic thing that I missed (although obvious) is that even though the compiler deduces "not-null state", it doesn't actually effect the variable type in any way. So the type is still double? and string? ToString() is invoked.

@vvv444 yes, null-state analysis is static analysis, nothing more. More over the nullable reference types are not actually separate types (i.e. they are represented with the same type in runtime unlike the nullable value types, which introduces some confusion at times, for example - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72911604/nullability-and-generics-in-net-6/72911969#72911969)
